# Generate sequence of dates used in for loop

Tags: postgresql, time-series

I have a series of tables partitioned by dates and named in the following format:

```
public.schedule_20121018
```

Is there a way to generate a sequence of dates in the above `20121018` pattern so that I can do a for loop `SELECT` through `information_schema.tables`?

For now I've got

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
AND table_schema = 'public'
AND table_name like 'schedule_%'
ORDER BY table_name;
```

But for instance I need the last 7 days' record so that a date sequence shall be starting from `20121012` to `20121018`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND table_schema = 'public'
    AND table_name in (
        select 'schedule_' || to_char(d, 'YYYYMMDD')
        from 
        generate_series(current_date - 7, current_date - 1, '1 day') s(d)
        )
ORDER BY table_name;
```

Older Postgresql versions:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND table_schema = 'public'
    AND table_name in (
        select 'schedule_' || to_char(current_date - d, 'YYYYMMDD')
        from 
        generate_series(7, 1, -1) s(d)
        )
ORDER BY table_name;
```

Comment: Thank you Clodoaldo. I tried `to_char` but it gives `ERROR:  multiple decimal points for function "to_char"`. Have you tried it on your machine or should I use some other functions? I suspect it's I'm using a lower Postgresql version 8.2? Thanks!

Comment: @Rock Added a version for older postgresql versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot Clodoaldo. I figured it out in another way `select regexp_replace((current_date + s.a), '-', '', 'g') as dates from generate_series(-7,-1,1) as s(a);` but yours is much cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `generate_series`, possibly with `to_char` for formatting.

```
regress=# select generate_series(DATE '20121012', DATE '20121018', interval '1' day);
    generate_series     
------------------------
 2012-10-12 00:00:00+08
 2012-10-13 00:00:00+08
 2012-10-14 00:00:00+08
 2012-10-15 00:00:00+08
 2012-10-16 00:00:00+08
 2012-10-17 00:00:00+08
 2012-10-18 00:00:00+08
(7 rows)
```