# Do SELECT from a set of tables one by one

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, partitioning

I have a set of tables partitioned by dates and named in the following format:

```
public.schedule_20121019
```

I can successfully [return a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977261/generate-sequence-of-dates-used-in-for-loop) of these tables for a specific number of days:

```
SELECT 'public.schedule_' || to_char(current_date - d, 'YYYYMMDD')
FROM generate_series(6, 0, -1) s(d);
```

but what is a good way do `select * from` each one of these tables and insert the results into a new table? Thanks!

Comment: Are duplicates to be expected? If yes, do you want to keep them or group them? Group how *exactly*?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter each table is unique and I need search through them one by one.

Comment: I am referring to rows, not tables. While returning rows from *multiple* tables you have to define how to resolve these conflicts or guarantee there are none. Also, define "partitioned"? Did you create them with inheritance like outlined [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-partitioning.html)? Then @Clodoaldo's answer should cover it. Else ...

Comment: Thank you Erwin. I think my answer and comment to @Clodoaldo shall make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are partitioned by date then query the parent table. If you want to create a new table:

```
create table another_table as
select *
from schedule_parent
where the_date between current_date - 6 and current_date
```

If you want to insert into an existent table:

```
insert into another_table
select *
from schedule_parent
where the_date between current_date - 6 and current_date
```

A partitioned table has a check constraint:

```
create table schedule_20121012 (
    check (date the_date = date '20012-10-12')
) inherits (schedule_parent);
```

So when you query for a date from the parent table the planner knows which table to look for:

```
select * from schedule_parent where date the_date = date '20012-10-12'
```

I have a set of tables using inheritance. The table `usuarios` has children partitioned by one of its columns. One of its children:

```
\d+ usuarios_25567
             Table "public.usuarios_25567"
 Column  |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Description 
---------+---------+-----------+---------+-------------
 usuario | integer | not null  | plain   | 
 data    | integer | not null  | plain   | 
 wus     | integer | not null  | plain   | 
 pontos  | real    | not null  | plain   | 
Indexes:
    "ndx_usuarios_25567" UNIQUE, btree (usuario)
Check constraints:
    "b25567" CHECK (data = 25567)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_usuarios_25567" FOREIGN KEY (data) REFERENCES datas(data_serial)
Inherits: usuarios
Has OIDs: no
```

Its check constraint is the `data` column. Now look at the query plan when I use that column to filter the query on the parent table:

```
explain select * from usuarios where data = 25567;
                                          QUERY PLAN                                          
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=0.00..26590.45 rows=1484997 width=16)
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..26590.45 rows=1484997 width=16)
         ->  Seq Scan on usuarios  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=16)
               Filter: (data = 25567)
         ->  Seq Scan on usuarios_25567 usuarios  (cost=0.00..26590.45 rows=1484996 width=16)
               Filter: (data = 25567)
(6 rows)
```

It will only look at that table. Not the other hundreds of tables.

Comment: thank you Clodoaldo. it is because each table I'm dealing with has millions of records so searching based on dates in the parent table may not be feasible, which is why we need the partitions.

Comment: @Rock If the condition contains the same terms of the constraint then yes.

Answer (score 1):

For information on partitioning, refer to the fine [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html). There is wealth of inforamtion, and then some. You will be using table inheritance to do the partitioning.

Two caveats: Make sure that partitioning actually solves a problem. It is good for dropping old data, and querying for date ranges. Realistically, the separate partitions should have at least millions of rows to make it worhwile.

Another caveat: In it's current state, Postgresql's partitioning works for tens of tables. Hundreds seems like a stretch. Consider monthly partitions, instead of daily.

Comment: thanks maniek. actually the tables I'm dealing with do have millions of records and we need daily partition in that way.

Answer (score 1):

I figured a way to work it out:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION looper(_schema varchar, _partition varchar,
                                  _traceback integer, _table varchar)
RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE row RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR row IN
        SELECT table_schema
            , table_name
        FROM
            information_schema.tables
        WHERE
            table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
        AND
            table_schema = _schema
        AND
            table_name IN (
                SELECT _partition || to_char(current_date - d, 'YYYYMMDD')
                FROM
                    generate_series(_traceback, 0, -1) s(d)
            )
        ORDER BY table_name
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || _table || ' SELECT schedule_date FROM ' ||
            quote_ident(row.table_schema) || '.' ||
            quote_ident(row.table_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```